# Best Way To Visualize Two Plots In Python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm trying to compare some Blast Motion bat sensor data (during practice) to actual Softball game statistics pulled from Game Changer. Blast Motion has a lot of metrics and i'm curious to see if something we practiced in a particular week made in-game stats better. For example, on 1/26/20 we practiced increasing "On Plane Score" which is used to determine the correct bat path compared to point of impact. I have two CSV spreadsheets with data. One is Game Changer and the other is Blast data.

I can plot the dataframes with df.plot() but i don't know how to size them correctly. On one plot the dates are spaced and the other, squished together. What's the best way to look at these? Sorry, total beginner here.

````
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

sbgame = pd.read_csv('sbgame.csv', index_col=0)
blasttotal = pd.read_csv('blast.csv', index_col=0)

#groups data by date, then gets the average. There are multiple swings on each data an i need the average first before plotting#

blast_group_by_date = blasttotal.groupby(by=['Date']) 
blast_group_by_avg = blast_group_by_date.mean()

#Gets all rows and the first 4 columns: Date, Plane Score, Connection Score, and Rotation Score##

blast_scores = blast_group_by_avg.iloc[:,[0,1,2]]

##Grouping Softball games by date. Multiple games are played each tournament date##

sbgame_group_by_date = sbgame.groupby(by=['Date']) 


##Averaging the game date by date##

sbgame_group_by_avg = sbgame_group_by_date.mean()

##Getting all rows. Getting Hits,Base on Balls,OPS columns##

sbgame_scores = sbgame_group_by_avg.iloc[:,[2,13,18]]

##Plotting data##

sbgame_scores.plot(title='SB Data',grid=True, marker='o')

blast_scores.plot(title='Blast Data',grid=True, marker='o')```

[Blast Data][1]


[Softball Game Data][2]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6CuXG.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVKdc.png
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subplots are a great way of controlling the individual layout of a graph. 
There's really good documentation [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/subplots_demo.html).
I'd be happy to answer any questions you have about the docs. Basically just gives you control over the composition of the individual graphs.

Comment: I started down this path but i didn't know how to get 3 plots from one CSV and 1 plot from the other CSV. So i could compare 3 Blast metrics to the 1 Softball game metric



```blast_score_plots = plt.figure()

blast_plane = blast_score_plots.add_subplot(2,2,1)

blast_connection = blast_score_plots.add_subplot(2,2,2)

blast_rotation = blast_score_plots.add_subplot(2,2,3)```

Comment: So the line: fig, axs = plt.subplots(#,#) creates the dimensionality of the subplots and how they're laid out. axs[#,#].plot(x,y) will designate where in the grid your plot will go. I would turn the values your plotting into discrete arrays of Xs and Ys etc., so you can easily just insert them into the plot.

Comment: I've also heard of Seaborn. Would this be a better way to visualize data or is Matplotlib the go-to?

Comment: Personally have no experience with Seaborn, whatever has the best docs and makes the most sense to you